# Scrotal swelling affecting a child

Tags: penis, swelling, disorders, cure

I would like to know any better remedies except operation available for **scrotal swelling in a child** ?

My sister's son is affected with this... why does it occur for 1 and half year child?

And is there any solution except operation available? In my localities they say different reason was not satisfied. Simple google search told me disorder name but I didn't understand why it occurs and its cure.

Can anybody tell me? would be great help and will save a child life... we are waiting to operate but we would like to cure without operation.

Child feels pain when somebody touches.

Comment: I would not like to give answer, as I don't have the right knowledge to read medical websites, and so are most of us.....even if given explanation by doctors, we are not able to understand most medical consequences/implications or alternatives etc.  

But googling and information search I can do it..so here are some links pertaining exactly to your children + scrotal + swelling problem in general...but may not be directly applicable to your case specifically:

https://www.stanfordchildrens.org/en/topic/default?id=scrotal-swelling-in-children-160-59

Comment: I know not the technical meaning of these details, best is to consult people who are able or interested to explained to you:
(1) https://www.medicinenet.com/swollen_testicles/symptoms.htm  
(2) https://www.msdmanuals.com/home/kidney-and-urinary-tract-disorders/symptoms-of-kidney-and-urinary-tract-disorders/scrotal-swelling
(3) https://healthcare.utah.edu/healthfeed/postings/2019/11/swollen-testicle.php
(4) https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hydrocele/symptoms-causes/syc-20363969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the right place to ask that question, you/your sister need to talk with the medical professional who evaluated and diagnosed him.

In the USA, whoever proposes to do surgery has a legal and ethical obligation to explain it thoroughly (the reasons for the procedure with the risks, benefits, and alternatives) to the patient or legal guardian of the child BEFORE the procedure. 
 Informed consent.  I don't know the law in your country but there must be something similar.

On Health SE we can't diagnose or propose treatment plans.  Even for a doctor, without examining the child, it would be unethical to give treatment recommendations.  Yes there are some causes of scrotal swelling that MIGHT REQUIRE surgery (for example [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testicular_torsion), or often [inguinal hernia](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/inguinal-hernia/symptoms-causes/dxc-20206367)), sometimes medical emergencies requiring *immediate* surgery. But no one online should diagnose your nephew's case.

I recommend you write down your specific questions,  print out a picture like the one I attached, and TAKE THEM BOTH to the physician (or another for a second opinion if you feel it is needed) to explain it to your sister (and you).

[image]